# How to add a library project as a dependecy to my Android Maven project

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I'm creating on `IntelliJ IDEA 12` a main Project (using Maven) and a module that is my library. I need to add the module as a dependency to my main Project.

How can I do this?

Comment: you want to add your sub project as a library of of your main project ?

Comment: Exactly. I need to separate my application in more than one Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this is the `pom.xml` of the **main project**, I add my custom library (`groupId` -> com.example.app and `artifactId` -> library)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.myapp{groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-example-app{artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is the `pom.xml` of the **library project**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you install the library project on your machine (`mvn clean install`), it will be accessible to `IntelliJ IDEA`

Comment: But I have to run this maven command everytime I recompile my library until final release?